# wso2 data mapper attribute manipulation

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am currently using the BETA 2 version of wso2 esb tooling. it is a great improvement from the previous version that I used which is the ALPHA version. so for my question is that is there a way to manipulate the attribute that was mapped from data mapper? so for example is that if have a response minute with a data type of integer and value of `150` and I want to concatenate a string on that integer so the result should be `150 min`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can do a type conversion using 'ToString' operation and and then use 'Concat' operation to concatenate the two strings. You can find more details on the latest improvements of Data Mapper at : https://nuwanpallewela.wordpress.com/2016/07/16/understanding-wso2-data-mapper-5-0-0/

Comment: Is it possible to concat an attribute with a defined string on runtime? ex. `time + " mins"`

Comment: You can use a constant operator to define " mins" as a constant string and concat that with the attribute.